# Content Add-in inserted in Desktop PowerPoint not recognised when working online and vice versa

Tags: office-js

We have created a simple **Content Add-in** (using office js api) that can be inserted in both Desktop and Online (browser) versions of **PowerPoint**.

The Desktop and Online versions share the same manifest. They have no difference in functionality and none have any special requirements defined in the manifest.

As they share the **same manifest**, they obviously share the **same plugin id**.

Never the less, add-in content **inserted in web** version version is not recognized when **viewd in the desktop** version. The error:

> This add-in could not be started

And add-in content **inserted in desktop** version is not recognized when **viewed in the web** version. The error:

> This add-in is not available in Office Online. Open this document in
>   desktop version of Office to use the add-in.

Is this only because we use **sideloading**, or do we do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you side-load an Add-in it automatically generates a random `id` for the add-in. So each time you side-load, you will end up with a new and unique `id` regardless of what was defined in the manifest.

Since side-loading is a dev/test rather than deployment scenario, this ensures that a side-loaded Add-in in dev/test won't conflict with any existing production Add-ins. It is very common for example for there to be a build in development, another build being tested, and the previous release in the Store.

For developing and testing scenarios that rely on a common `id` (the `settings` property bag is a prime example), the guidance is to use an [Office 365 Developer Tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/office/profile) and [Central Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment). This allows you to load your dev/test build in a non-production environment and deploy to multiple platforms (Windows, Mac, Web, etc.) using a common `id`.